# How to use azure api management to do custom access token check and enrich data in request

Tags: azure-api-management

All the incoming request to api management will have a token in a header, before backend service is hit token has to be verified. To verify token a GET tokenVallidationApi is to be hit and the response will tell us whether the token is valid or not. If the response exists for token validation , we have to take out few entries from response and enrich the body/header to hit the backend api. I am very new to  api management tool and just figuring out how can we achieve this with azure api management?

Answer (score 4):

This is possible. You would have to implement your policies like something below

**1. Validate Token**
For this, you would first call the validation endpoint using [`send-request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#SendRequest). You could also implement caching using [value caching policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies) for multiple requests.

The doc also highlights how you can extract value from the response body.

**2. Transform Body & Headers**
For headers, you would use the [`set-header`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetHTTPheader) policy and for the body, you would use the [`set-body`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBody) policy.

Comment: One more question - can we add Ocp-apim-subscription-key as header to validate subscription ?